# VS2017 running debug selected tests does not open the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I have Specflow/Nunit tests that used to debug fine last Friday (16-Nov-2018). The debugger suddenly stopped yesterday (20-Nov-2018) without me changing anything.

Steps: 
1. Select any test on the Test Explorer window
2. Right click the test and select "Debug Selected Tests"
After this, the debugger should start and it should stop at the breakpoint but it doesn't. Instead I get an output relating to testhost.x86.exe and being unable to find PDB files (please find attached).

I have already tried the following:
1. Update to the latest version 15.9.2
2. Uninstall and reinstall VS2017 Professional (done twice already)
3. Add the system variable `__UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH__`
4. Disable Just My Code in Tools > Options > Debugging > General
5. Tick Microsoft Symbol Servers in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols

I have no idea what is going on and I have not changed anything yesterday or Monday. Please help.

Here are some of the messages from the output:
`'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: domain-e649a6ea-Test.API.dll): Loaded 'D:\Repos\Test\Test.API\bin\Debug\RestSharp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

`'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. Module was built without symbols.`

`'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'D:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\testhost.x86.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`

`The program '[13292] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: Are you trying to debug a Release build?

Answer (score 3):

Install NUnit3testAdapter from Manage Nuget packages and restart your visual studio. this helps me :)

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the "NUnit 3 Test Adapter" extension helped in my case.